# javax.xml.soap.SOAPException: java.security.ProviderException: Could not derive key

Tags: java, soap, ws-security

I am sending a SOAP request to an endpoint. I am using Axis2. Below code is working fine in my environment, but it is giving an exception on a Linux setup. Linux setup is using a Message broker between client and the server.

```
public SOAPMessage createSOAPMessage(SOAPMessage request, String endpoint) throws Exception {


    ConfigurationContext configurationContext = getConfigurationContext();

    // initialize URL
    URL url;
    try {
        url = new URL(endpoint);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        throw new Exception("Invalid Endpoint: " + endpoint + ", " + e.getMessage(), e);
    }

    // initialize and set Options
    Options options = new Options();
    options.setTo(new EndpointReference(url.toString()));

    try {
        serviceClient = new ServiceClient(configurationContext, null);
        operationClient = serviceClient.createClient(ServiceClient.ANON_OUT_IN_OP);
    } catch (AxisFault e) {
        throw new SOAPException(e.getMessage(), e);
    }

    options.setProperty(Constants.Configuration.CHARACTER_SET_ENCODING, 
            request.getProperty(SOAPMessage.CHARACTER_SET_ENCODING));
    operationClient.setOptions(options);
    MessageContext requestMsgCtx = new MessageContext();
    SOAPEnvelope envelope = SAAJUtil.toOMSOAPEnvelope(request.getSOAPPart().getDocumentElement());
    requestMsgCtx.setProperty(HTTPConstants.CHUNKED, "false");

    Map<String,String> httpHeaders = null;
    for (Iterator it = request.getMimeHeaders().getAllHeaders(); it.hasNext(); ) {
        MimeHeader header = (MimeHeader)it.next();
        String name = header.getName().toLowerCase();
        if (name.equals("soapaction")) {
            requestMsgCtx.setSoapAction(header.getValue());
        } else {
            if (httpHeaders == null) {
                httpHeaders = new HashMap<String,String>();
            }
            httpHeaders.put(header.getName(), header.getValue());
        }
    }

    if (httpHeaders != null) {
        requestMsgCtx.setProperty(HTTPConstants.HTTP_HEADERS, httpHeaders);
    }

    MessageContext responseMsgCtx;

    try {
        requestMsgCtx.setEnvelope(envelope);
        operationClient.addMessageContext(requestMsgCtx);
        operationClient.execute(true);
        responseMsgCtx = operationClient.getMessageContext(WSDLConstants.MESSAGE_LABEL_IN_VALUE);
    } catch (AxisFault ex) {
        throw new SOAPException(ex.getMessage(), ex);
    }

    return getSOAPMessage(responseMsgCtx.getEnvelope());
}
```

Error is:

> javax.xml.soap.SOAPException: java.security.ProviderException: Could not derive key

Both the environments are using WS-security and using Java 1.8u51. I double checked the certificate and it looks good.

Please advice.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was because of the Bouncy Castle jar loaded in the JVM on Linux machine. Bouncy castle jar was a part of our project. We used below lines of code to list the securities libraries in the JVM for Linux setup and bouncy castle was one of them. We deleted the jar from the environment and it started working. Please note java version on Linux machine is 1.8u51.

```
try {
        Provider pArray[] = Security.getProviders();
        if (log.isDebugEnabled()) {
            log.debug("Availble number of Providers are -> " + pArray.length);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < pArray.length; i++) {
            Provider p = pArray[i];
            if (log.isDebugEnabled()) {
                log.debug(p + ", Info-> " + p.getInfo() + ", Class -> " + p.getClass().getName());
            }
            for (Enumeration e = p.keys(); e.hasMoreElements();) {
                if (log.isDebugEnabled()) {
                    log.debug("\t" + e.nextElement());
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        if (log.isErrorEnabled()) {
            log.error("List all security provider failed. " + e);
        }
    }
```

Instead of deleting the jar we can try upgrading java to latest Java 8 version.